# Get information about logical drives on a system MacOS OSX .net core

Tags: c#, .net, macos, .net-core

I need to get information about mount points. Using DriveInfo.GetDrives() on Windows I easily achieved the desired result, but on Mac it does not work as I thought.
DriveInfo.GetDrives()
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fostn.png)

This is what I get.

And I need to get the result like this (this is a program from another developer)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kqiUA.png)

Tell me how can I find all the mount points correctly?
P.S. Sorry for my English

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow! Please provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and give us some more info on the specific output you are hoping to achieve. Are you trying to make an image similar to the one you posted, or are you trying to just extract the drive names from the data you receive?

Comment: @bisen2
I am trying to get information about disks. Their number, names, size, mount points. But importantly, I'm only interested in logical drives. Images of programs, etc. I'm not interested.